# Qt 5.0.2 and OpenGL 3+ rendering problems

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-3, qglwidget

I have written tiny OpenGL engine which uses 3+ functions. I am currently trying to integrate my engine in QGLWidget and have problems. When rendering obj model without qt framework I have got expected results, but when using Qt my OpenGL buffers are corrupted in some way so that I see wrong result or even nothing.

Without Qt:

[image: renders nice without Qt]

In QGLWidget:

[image: strange behavious in QGLWidget]

I want to ask whether Qt changes any OpenGL states between QGLWidget::paintGL() calls.
My objects are initialized and rendered in the following order:

Initialization:

```
Create and bind vertex array
Create and bind vertex buffer
Fill vertex buffer (works fine - obj loader tested many times)
Calls to glVertexAttribPointer() and glEnableVertexAttribArray()
```

Rendering:

```
Bind vertex array
Shaders, uniforms, etc.
glDraw*()
```

Comment: Looks like your textures aren't loading? I figure the branches/leaves of your trees are textured polygons, and they look like solid polygons in the second picture. If you are loading the textures from files, did you check that they still load successfully?

Comment: @Reto Koradi, textures are loaded correctly and are bound just before vertex array. Furthermore, this is not the only problem: vertex buffers are corrupted in some way: just look at the palm trunk and boxes.

Comment: True. Hard to tell what it could be. You called `glGetError()`, and made sure that it doesn't complain about anything? And you're only making GL calls in methods where the context has been created, and is current? It's possible that there was already a bug in your code, and you were just fortunate that it worked before. Particularly, I would carefully look at the management of all object ids. Make sure that they are all generated properly, not deleted by accident (quite common when wrapping them in C++ objects), and that the right ids are used everywhere.

Comment: @Reto Koradi, I have figured out some interesting details. I have logged out to a file a list vertices and texture coordinates which are loaded from OBJ file. It seems that with Qt framework components of glm::vec3 and glm::vec2 (I use GLM as math library) are rounded to int values in some way. That is why there are no textures: texture coordinates are corrupted - (0,0) instead of float values. I still do not understand what happens. By the way, I use GCC and QtCreator and link my app with engine statically.

Comment: @Reto Koradi, I found out that the problem is caused by std::stof() which returns floats in my non-Qt project but in Qt project that values become rounded. I have no idea why this happens since my engine  has nothing to do with Qt anyway. The engine library and both non-Qt and Qt projects are compiled with G++.

Comment: Maybe the header declaring `stof()` is not included, and it falls back to the ancient C default of assuming that undeclared functions return `int`? Looks like the function is declared in `<string>`. It's also a C++11 feature, so maybe it needs certain compiler flags to become available?

Comment: @Reto Koradi, C++11 is enabled and <string> is included. As I said, everything works nice in non-Qt project and I still can't find any differences between these two projects (except Qt libraries, of course).

Comment: @RostakaGmfun did you ever find a reason why this `stof` truncation was occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is because Qt is setting the C locale on your system for you, to something that is expecting floats to be comma delimited instead of period delimited.

You can work around it by resetting the local to something else immediately after you invoke `QApplication`

For example:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "POSIX");
```

Comment: So many time has passed since then... However, your answer is genuine! Thanks anyway!

Comment: I figured since it hit me too, I'd go ahead and put up an answer for the next person! Your question was the only one I could find.